# Custom Dialog's snippet is not working

Tags: android

I have a piece of code for creating Custom Dialog box in android. This code does not work on clicking the button.

[image]

[image]

Can any one tell me where am I mistaking ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.. Whenever you have find a button inside your custom dialog box use this code..   **`Button btn_cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);`**

```
 Custom_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Profile.this);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_dialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("This is the Title");
                    Button btn_cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
                    btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();   

            });
```

Comment: Vishnummm93 thanks for sharing your knowledge but this code is not working

Comment: @AliShah Okay then try one thing remove all the dialog thing in the buttonclick function and just give a toast message and check whether its working or not... If toast message works we can confirm the problem is within the inside of the function .. Please try that and let me know it.. I will try my best to help you.. The above code is working fine for me lets check it out

Comment: Appreciate your struggle to help me out. As I am new and I am not able to state my problem efficiently, vishnu I want you to please access my laptop and understand it yourself, if it is possible to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Custom_dialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You Clicked the button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        });
```

Please check whether this code is working or not... it is used to check if your button click is working or not. If you get a toast message let me know it..

Comment: ('quote = new String("The Quote under else block is showing");
    mtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        String datestr = "19-03";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
                Date currentDate = new Date();

        if (datestr.equals(sdf.format(currentDate))) {
            mtv.setText("today date is 18 of march");
        }

        else {

            mtv.setText(quote);
        }')

Comment: [quote = new String("The Quote under else block is showing");
    mtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        String datestr = "19-03";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
                Date currentDate = new Date();

        if (datestr.equals(sdf.format(currentDate))) {
            mtv.setText("today date is 18 of march");
        }

        else {

            mtv.setText(quote);
        }]

Comment: {quote = new String("The Quote under else block is showing");
    mtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        String datestr = "19-03";
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
                Date currentDate = new Date();

        if (datestr.equals(sdf.format(currentDate))) {
            mtv.setText("today date is 18 of march");
        }

        else {

            mtv.setText(quote);
        }}